# SAS insert value with proc sql

Tags: sas, proc-sql

So I have a rather interesting problem. I am trying to insert a current date in specific formats and styles, but for some reason it seems to fail. I know its not a formatting issue... But idk how to fix it. a data step solution is welcomed as well... Here's what works.

```
proc sql;
create table work.test
(test_Id char(50), test_Name char(50), cur_Mo char(1), cur_Qtr char(1), entered_Date char(8));
insert into work.test 
values('201703','2017 Mar','0','0','24APR17')
values('201704','2017 Apr','0','0','24APR17')
values('201706','2017 Jun','1','0','23JUN17');
quit;
```

Here's what doesn't:

```
proc sql;
    insert into work.test 
    values(catx('',put(year(today()),4.),case when month(today())< 10 then catx('','0',put(month(today()),2.)) else put(month(today()),2.)end) ,catx(' ',[put(year(today()),4.),put(today(),monname3.))],'1','0',put(today(),date7.));
quit;
```

Comment: You cannot put functions in a VALUES clause.  Just actual values.

Comment: I figured that would be the case, is there another approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the %SYSFUNC() macro function to call most other SAS function in macro code.  So to generate today's date in DATE7 format you could use:

```
insert into work.test (date)
  values("%sysfunc(date(),date7)")
;
```

Comment: I do have a follow up - how do I combine the month and date so that it follows: 201701,201702 and so on?

Comment: SAS has lots of formats for dates. YYMMN6 would generate date strings in the format of YYYYMM.

Comment: In my case my solution was to use this in an Insert Statement: `values("%sysfunc(date(),yymmn6.)","%sysfunc(date(),yymon7.)",'1','0',"%sysfunc(date(),date7.)");` For now this meets the requirements of my current problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The way I'd probably do it is to use a data step to make a dataset that you would insert, and then insert that dataset.

You can use `insert into (...) select (...) from (...)` syntax in SAS, and the data step is much more flexible as to allowing you to define columns.

For example:

```
proc sql;
  create table class like sashelp.class;
quit;

proc sql;
   insert into class
     select * from sashelp.class;
quit;
```

Or you can specify only certain variables:

```
proc sql;
    insert into class (name, age)
      select name, age from sashelp.class;
quit;



data to_insert;
  name= 'Wilma';
  sex = 'F';
  age = 29;
  height = 61.2;
  weight = 95.3;
run;

proc sql;
  insert into class
    select * from to_insert;
quit;
```

Just make sure you either explicitly list the variables to insert/select, or you have the order exactly right (it matches up by position if you use `*` like I do above).

Comment: Thanks for the advice, what if there was a date function involved as one of the variables? I'll be trying this as well! Thanks!

Comment: In the data step that's not a problem; the date function should resolve in the data step (i.e., don't insert the text "today()", but `age=today()-birthdate;` should be fine, since it does the calculation in the data step).

Comment: If you are inserting data from a table using a `SELECT` instead of constants  using `VALUES` then you can use functions.